# IntelliJ inspection does not see repository bean

Tags: java, jpa, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

I can inject dependencies on repositories in Spring JPA and it works. Simultaneously, IntelliJ does not see it is injectable:

[image]

Repository is just an interface according to JPA:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {


   @Query("SELECT U FROM User U WHERE U.screenName = 'root'")
   User getRootUser();

   User findByScreenName(String screeNmae);

}
```

**UPDATE**

I have added some facets

[image]

but not sure it is enough (apparently not).

I have no XML files :)

It is Spring Boot app.

Comment: Did you add required facets?

Comment: Did you add spring facet and configure it with any spring xml's you have.

Comment: According to the [spring docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html), you need to either **1)** declare the repositories packages in xml format `<repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories">` or **2)** java configs with `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.acme.repositories")`. I also suspect it may work if you simply annotate it with `@Repository` but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Is your repository class annotated with @Repository?

Comment: Annotating the repositories with `@Repository` solved the issue for me!